# Configure ElasticSearch for `+` RFC7159?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to configure ElasticSearch to accept newer JSON specifications?

I need to represent positive, negative, and unsigned numbers in JSON for indexing in ElasticSearch.

e.g.

```
[
    { "confidence":   0},
    { "confidence":   0.417763},
    { "confidence":   -0.296771},
]
```

[RFC 7158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6) would support this:

```
minus = %x2D                ; -
plus  = %x2B                ; +
zero  = %x30                ; 0
```

I cannot find a configuration for that, so I am left with a workaround.
Transform every field named "confidence" to either

- a range without negative numbers (0-1)

  ```
    {"type": "integer_range", "gte":0, "lte":1}
  ```
- a scaled_float in an object that indicates sign with a separate field

  ```
    {
        "properties": {
          "confidence": {
            "type": "scaled_float",
            "scaling_factor": 10000000
          },
          "negative": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
    }
  ```

json-schema appears to be accepted in a PUT mapping.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "mappings": {
    ...
   }
{

{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "bakeoff-rfc"
}
```

I am using ES 6.2.2, the latest supported by my cloud provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to map your confidence field as a `float` or `double` and then in the source document add them as a string.

Create the index mapping like this:

```
PUT rfc7158
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "confidence": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then add your data like this and you'll get no errors:

```
POST rfc7158/doc/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "confidence": "0" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "confidence": "-0.296771" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "confidence": "+0.8723734" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "confidence": "0.7672323" }
```

When running the following aggregation, you'll see that `+0.8723734` is the max and `-0.296771` is the min as expected

```
POST rfc7158/_search  
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "minconfidence": {
      "min": {
        "field": "confidence"
      }
    },
    "maxconfidence": {
      "max": {
        "field": "confidence"
      }
    }
  }
}
```